# Find documents including element in Array field with mongomapper?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I am new to mongodb/mongomapper and can't find an answer to this.

I have a mongomapper class with the following fields

```
key :author_id, Integer
key :partecipant_ids, Array
```

Let's say I have a "record" with the following attributes:

```
{ :author_id => 10, :partecipant_ids => [10,15,201] }
```

I want to retrieve all the objects where the partecipant with id 15 is involved.
I did not find any mention in the documentation.

The strange thing is that previously I was doing this query

```
MessageThread.where :partecipant_ids => [15]
```

which worked, but after (maybe) some change in the gem/mongodb version it stopped working.
Unfortunately I don't know which version of mongodb and mongomapper I was using before.

Comment: What version of rails/mongomapper/mongodb etc are you using now?

Comment: rails 3.0.10, mongo (1.5.0), mongo_mapper (0.10.1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the current versions of MongoMapper, this will work:

```
MessageThread.where(:partecipant_ids => 15)
```

And this should work as well...

```
MessageThread.where(:partecipant_ids => [15])
```

...because plucky autoexpands that to:

```
MessageThread.where(:partecipant_ids => { :$in => [15] })
```

(see https://github.com/jnunemaker/plucky/blob/master/lib/plucky/criteria_hash.rb#L121)

I'd say take a look at your data and try out queries in the Mongo console to make sure you have a working query.  MongoDB queries translate directly to MM queries except for the above (and a few other minor) caveats.  See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying

Comment: Also see the plucky tests, they are probably clearer to read than the source: https://github.com/jnunemaker/plucky/blob/master/test/plucky/test_criteria_hash.rb#L144

Comment: strange fact. With MessageThread.where(:partecipant_ids => ['15']) it works. For some reason it's treated like an array of strings now? I am 100% sure that before the upgrade it was working with integers.

Comment: You can try adding :typecast => 'Integer' to your :partecipant_ids key.  I'm not sure if that will break the many :in association.