# How do you call "contains?" on a MongoMapper Array in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper

I want to know how to check if an array element exists inside of a MongoMapper Array. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297553/find-documents-including-element-in-array-field-with-mongomapper) is the closest I could find, but it addresses queries rather than simply using a document you already have.

My User model contains the line

```
key :roles, Array
```

The 'roles' array contains strings such as 'admin' or 'user.' For authorization, I need to call something like the following method on an instance of User:

```
if user.roles.contains?('admin')
    # Do administrative stuff.
end
```

But when I try to call 'contains?' Ruby complains that there is no such method:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `contains?' for #<Array:0x007fc845cd8948>):
    app/models/ability.rb:11:in `initialize'
    app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

If there's no way to do this, then how do I convert the Array into a Ruby array to call 'contains?'? Calling to_a isn't doing it:

```
if user.roles.to_a.contains?('admin')  # etc...
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.13, Ruby-1.9.3-p392, and MongoMapper 0.12.0 on Mountain Lion.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with MongoDB so this suggestion is noobish. What does `user.roles` return as?

Comment: The answer is... Ruby arrays have no `contains?` method. It's called `include?`. Sigh...

Comment: @jason328 It was returning `#<Array:0x007fc845cd8948>`. Anyway, silly mistake on my part not to know the correct method name.

Comment: Got it. I was unsure if contains was a method provided by MongoMapper. Glad to know it works now.

Answer (score 2):

the function you are looking for is `include?`, so the expression would be: `user.roles.include?('admin')`

However since you mentioned mongomapper, if you were preforming a query on the roles array you would do the fallowing:

```
User.where( :roles => 'admin' )
```

You can also search an array with an array

```
User.where( :roles.in => ['admin'] )
```

for a query with admin or user you can do:

```
User.where( :$or => [{:roles => 'admin'},{:roles => 'user'}] )
```

and you can do and just the same:

```
User.where( :$and => [{:roles => 'admin'},{:roles => 'user'}] )
```

Comment: @muistooshort - yep i mistyped that